# How to toggle this modal from PHP on submit code?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have this modal:

```
 <div class="container">          
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I would like to toggle it when I am executing some PHP code

```
  if(//){
      //toggle modal
    }
```

What I have tried so far was setting a flag to true when function is executed and then in html I do this:

```
    <?php if ($show_modal) : ?>
    <script>
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it still doesn't work. Any one knows whats going on here?

EDIT: all the plugins I am loading in the html header

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Did you emmeded the jquery files correctly? Can you show, how you link the those files??

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane thanks for commenting, I just updated the question with the plugin I am loading In html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have set jquery plugin twice, it might be getting difficult. So, you have 2 options in my mind. First, you could move bootstrap plugin to the bottom and remove one of the jquery plugins. Just before body ends. like:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php if ($show_modal) : ?>
    <script>
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or, you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Here goes yor code
});
```

As you import bootstrap, and again added jquery plugin. You have to use `document.ready` to insure all files are loaded, then we will use the function.

*Note:- You might have to move the jquery table plugin after bootstrap too, if you move the bootstrap.js. I am not sure about that, cos I haven't use that plugin yet.